# HTML and CSS gallery grid design

Tags: html, css

[How can I make this gallery with text please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY3Bk.png)

```css
.wrapper { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper>div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <img src="one.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="two.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="one.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="four.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="two.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="four.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share code please. When you are stuck with your code reach out for help.

Comment: @prettyInPink I already made the position of grid but I couldn't get the exact design of it

Comment: Still a student trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `repeat(3, 1fr)` make the width of the first column as 2fr.
Using background color to show the structure as I have no image.

```css
.wrapper { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper>div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.text {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <img src="one.jpg">
      <div class="text">Image 1</div> 
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="two.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="one.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="four.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="two.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="four.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but the images are" big-small-small " the big one stands out but the small images doesn't match the height of the big one.

Comment: Can you upload the images in the question code snippet?

Comment: how can i add it? there's an error when i upload the images

Comment: Can you share the screenshot how the ui looks when using this answer?

Comment: Can i post it here in comment section? i'll send the image on gdrive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xILCSOhtzWQGrBrKcxiPGbwrljTSBTGG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the issue will be solved by defining a max-height on the img.

Comment: I put image-height but  the image get smaller and in 100% stays the same